# How to fix a while loop with multiple conditions returning an error

Tags: r, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I have written code requesting the user to either type "2012" or "2013".  I then have a `while` loop check to see if the user types 2012 or 2013.

The request to enter a valid year is supposed to continue until the user enters a valid number.  However, I keep getting an error that an unexpected "{" occurs.  I cannot find why this is generating such an error in my code.

Here is the code:

```
yr_function <-function(){
   year_of_data <- as.numeric(readline("Is the year of concern 2012 or 2013? >>> "))
}

year_of_data = 0
While((year_of_data != 2012) | (year_of_data != 2013)){
    yr_function
if(year_of_data != (2012 | 2013),print("You must type either 2012 or 2013")
}
```

There error generated reads:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in "While((year_of_data != 2012) | (year_of_data != 2013)){"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is filled with non-correct R code, e.g. `year_of_data != (2012 | 2013)` and `if(), print()`. Also count your open and close brackets. Not to sound snarky, but I would advice you to read some R tutorials to get to know what correct R syntax is.

Comment: I'm fine with helping to debug, but this code only looks like R code, when in fact it is not correct R code.

Comment: I understand that both of you are fairly sensitive people, so I hope I didn't hurt your feelings with a question.  Specifically, I feel that the code is correct, especially based on the books that I have read in R.  Obviously it is not, so my misunderstanding is with the while construction - as posed in the question.

Why would one get an error here?  Because as far as my if is concerned, I can have a resultant of the condition within the if(condition, resultant), or I can write if(condition){resultant}.  I do understand that perhaps the condition is ill-written in the if condition.

Comment: IMHO this question got a response that was not really in proportion with its quality, and after lobbying to have it un-deleted I had just written a rather lengthy answer when the 5th close vote rolled in. I would appreciate some re-open votes. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the bones of what should be the general idea here, but you've been tripped up in several places by simple mistakes. Here's an annotated version that works as you describe:

```
yr_function <-function(){
   res <- as.numeric(readline("Is the year of concern 2012 or 2013? >>> "))
   if (is.na(res)){
    res <- -1
   }
   res
}
```

One of your first problems revolved around scope. You defined `year_of_data` both inside this function and just before your `while` loop. But the variable created inside the function will not refer to the one before the `while` loop. They exist in separate environments. So I modified this function to instead *return* the value that is input by the user.

You didn't discuss validation much, which is a big topic. I've added a very small bit of validation here. Basically, if the user enters something that can't be reasonably coerced to numeric, then you'll get an NA value, which will be a headache down the road. So I simply check for that and return -1 in that case. This is *not* a complete solution to the validation problem.

```
year_of_data <- 0
while((year_of_data != 2012) & (year_of_data != 2013)){
    year_of_data <- yr_function()
    if (!year_of_data %in% c(2012,2013)){
        print("You must type either 2012 or 2013")
    }else{
        break
    }
}
```

Here's the fixed `while` loop. First I fixed a few simple syntax errors (it's `while` not `While`, etc). Then I assigned the result of `yr_function()` to `year_of_data`, so that we can then check the resulting value and act accordingly.

Your attempt at the `if` condition (`year_of_data != (2012 | 2013)`) was not syntactically correct, so I switched to checking if the value was contained in the vector `c(2012,2013)`.

Lastly, you had followed the `if` with a comma and then a print statement. The comma is another syntax error. So I added braces around the `print` statement, and added an `else` clause that breaks out of the `while` loop if the user entered something correct.

More generally, you may want to investigate the function `menu` for this sort of task. It will probably make the validation issues a bit simpler to deal with.

Comment: +1 for well crafted answer, and taking your time to help someone out.

Comment: Thank you Joran.  I really appreciate you doing this.  It is very helpful and helps me look down the road a bit.